# Unresolved compilation with PlayN + tripleplay

Tags: maven, playn

I've been working on this project for a couple of months, I came back to it this week and it seems that with the snapshotting of PlayN and tripleplay something broke, since I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot invoke fillRect(int, int, float, float) on the primitive type void

at tripleplay.ui.Background.createSolidLayer(Background.java:90)
at tripleplay.ui.bgs.SolidBackground.instantiate(SolidBackground.java:26)
at tripleplay.ui.Elements.layout(Elements.java:191)
at tripleplay.ui.Element.validate(Element.java:317)
at tripleplay.ui.Interface.paint(Interface.java:120)
at com.jengibre.h4ck1t.bouncer.Bouncer.paint(Bouncer.java:110)
at playn.java.JavaPlatform$1.paint(JavaPlatform.java:216)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5131)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:278)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1224)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1015)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:21)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1780)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3375)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

this is my metaproject pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qaMWx72C

and this is my java project pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=z3BF45yr

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting an older version of PlayN that does not have the fluent interfaces on Surface/Canvas.

You can run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

in your `core` submodule (in that directory) to see which versions of PlayN jar files are being used to build your project. Here's an example from one of my games:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ atlantis-core ---                                                   
[INFO] com.threerings.atlantis:atlantis-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT                                                                   
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.playn:playn-core:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT:compile                                                              
[INFO] +- com.threerings.nexus:nexus-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile                                                              
[INFO] |  \- com.threerings:react:jar:1.1:compile                                                                               
[INFO] +- com.threerings:tripleplay:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT:compile                                                                    
[INFO] +- com.samskivert:pythagoras:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT:compile                                                                    
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0:compile                                                                               
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile                                                                  
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
```

If you don't see playn-core:jar:1.0.1 or 1.0.2, (or 1.1-SNAPSHOT if you're building against your own PlayN build), then something is amiss. You can most likely remedy said mishap by adding a playn-core dependency directly to your `core/pom.xml`. Usually your top-level `pom.xml` will define the version of PlayN you're using on your project:

```
<properties>
  <playn.version>1.0.2</playn.version>
</properties>
```

Then your `core/pom.xml` will make use of that property to declare a `playn-core` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.playn</groupId>
  <artifactId>playn-core</artifactId>
  <version>${playn.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem was that I was referencing 1.0-SNAPSHOT of tripleplay, even thou I recreated the project and moved the sources, anyway, it's fixed now